# How come 말이야 is translated as "especially"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Someone said that 말이야 is translated as "especially" in the sentence. 
However, how can it be translated like that?
말 literally means "words, speech".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would say that 말 is **sometimes** a *function word* when it is used as 말이야, 말입니다, ... (Hereafter, I will use "말이다" to call them collectively). The phrase 말이다 is a sentence ender as jick mentioned. One more thing you should know is that it can also be used as a filler, which smooths out your sentences. Unlike other fillers, it *cannot* be used independently; for example, it *cannot* be placed at the very front of a sentence.

---

You can use 말이다 as a sentence ender to add some details to what you have just said:

> - 너 그거 봤어? 새로 나온 제품 **말이야**.
> - 그 사람 정말 대단하다. 시험이 엄청 어려웠는데 **말이지**.

or to emphasize what you are talking about:

> - 너 그거 봤어? 새로 나온 제품 **말이야**. (This could be translated as "Have you seen it? I'm talking about the new product.")
> - 그래, 너 **말이야**. (This could be translated as "Yes, I'm talking about you." Please note that it does **not** mean "Yes, these are your words." I have seen some people mistranslate this sentence.)

Removing the ender 말이다 leaves *incomplete* sentences, but you can regard it as the *omission* that occurs a lot in Korean.

You can also use 말이다 as a filler to draw the listener's attention:

> - 가: 그런데 **말이야**, 그거 알아?
>
>   나: 뭘?
>
> ---
>
> - 가: 내가 **말이지** 어제 공원에 갔는데 **말이지**... 아무도 없더라.
>
>   나: 정말로?
>
> ---
>
> - 그게 **말이다**, 어제 내가 큰 실수를 했어. (Note: 그게 and 말이다 are all fillers here. I mean, you can remove 그게 말이다 or 말이다 without changing the meaning of the sentence.)

Removing the filler 말이다 still leaves complete sentences.

---

I said "**sometimes**" above because 말 means words when 말 is modified by other words, as the following:

- 네가 거기에 언제 갔느냐는 **말이야**. ("I am asking when you went there"; more literally, "These are the **words**, 'When did you go there?'.")
- 저리 가란 **말이야**! ("I'm telling you, go away!")

Answer (score 1):

말이야 is definitely not "especially" - though I can see how you got confused, because it will be very natural in English to use "especially" here:

> That's astounding.  *Especially* in this age where everyone is only thinking of themselves.

But there's nothing special about *especially* here: it was chosen merely because it connects the two sentences nicely.

So, forget "especially", and think of 말이야 as: "I'm going to end the sentence here, even though it lacks some part needed to form a grammatical sentence, because the rest of the sentence should be extremely obvious from context."

That is, if we flesh it out, the full second sentence can be something like:

> 요즘처럼 자신의 이익만 생각하는 시대에 **저 할머니는 참 대단하시다.**

But that's repeating yourself, right?  (Or 동어반복, as Koreans say.)  Since there's no reason to repeat the same thing twice (in fact, it will sound pretty awkward), we just end the sentence with "말이야/말입니다", and let the listener fill in the blank.